# imagegrabwindow captures black screen

Tags: php, apache, windows-services

This issue is very common and the solution is to allow Apache to `interact with desktop`. So i allowed it

[image]

and restarted `Apache service` and still it captures black screen

Here is the code

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$Browser = new COM('InternetExplorer.Application');
$Browserhandle = $Browser->HWND;
$Browser->Visible = true;
$Browser->Fullscreen = true;
$Browser->Navigate('http://www.stackoverflow.com');

while($Browser->Busy){
  com_message_pump(4000);
}

$img = imagegrabwindow($Browserhandle, 0);
$Browser->Quit();
imagepng($img, 'screenshot.png');
?>
```

I am on `Windows 10 Pro build 10586`
Xampp `3.2.1`
PHP `5.6.8`

Comment: What version of Windows is the apache running on?